# Why my rewrite rule in htaccess is working in some case only?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I try to rewrite some of my URLs with a `.htaccess` file but it didn't work as expected.

This is the rewrite rule in my `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteRule ^(index|administration)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\.php)?$ index.php?c=$1&t=$2 [QSA]
```

When I go on `www.example.com/index/main`, I get a 404 error code.
So I try to change my rewrite rule to

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ index.php?c=index&t=main [QSA]
```

Then I go to `www.example.com/index.php` and the webpage displays perfectly with all the datas in `$_GET` (c = index and t = main).

So I don't know why my first rule is not working. Let me see if you have any idea.
Is it possible that my server wants to enter the index folder, then the main folder for my first rule without taking care of my `.htaccess` (`www.example.com/index/main`) ?

Comment: What generates the 404? Apache or your script? "Is it possible that my server wants to enter the index folder" - Is `index` a physical directory? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Make sure you've disabled MultiViews. ie. `Options -MultiViews`

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer, it perfectly works by disabling the MultiViews Option in my .htaccess file. Can you comment so I can validate your answer ?

Comment: I've added that as an answer and included more explanation about MultiViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that MultiViews (part of mod_negotiation) is disabled for this to work correctly. So, add the following at top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

If MultiViews is enabled (it's disabled by default, but some hosts do sometimes enable this in the server config) then when you request `/index/main` where `/index.php` already exists as a physical file then mod_negotiation will make an internal request for `index.php` *before* mod_rewrite is able to process the request. (If `index.html` also exists, then this might be found first.)

(MultiViews essentially enables extensionless URLs by mocking up type maps and searching for files in the directory - with the same basename - that would return a response with an appropriate mime-type.)

If this happens then your mod-rewrite directive is essentially ignored (the pattern does not match, since it would need to check for `index.php`) and `index.php` is called *without* the URL parameters that your mod_rewrite directive would otherwise append.

> it perfectly works by disabling the MultiViews Option in my .htaccess

This would ordinarily imply its *your* script (ie. `index.php`) that is triggering the 404 (perhaps due to missing URL parameters?), rather than Apache itself?

However, if you were seeing an Apache generated 404 then it would suggest either:

- You also have an `index.html` file, which is *found* before `index.php`. `.html` files do not ordinarily accept path-info (ie. `/main`) so would trigger a 404.
- OR, `AcceptPathInfo Off` is explicitly set elsewhere in the config, which would trigger a 404 when the request is internally rewritten to `/index.php/main` (by mod_negotiation).